# free alternative to iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a project not open source and I need to use something like iTextSharp , because iTextSharp licence say it should only be used in open sources

any alternative please

Comment: Please provide more information on what your goal is and not just on what tool you need to replace.

Comment: Yep, givers set limits, because takers rarely do. If you're a taker, you should expect having to give something back. If not money, then something else. That's the way the cookie crumbles.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are multiple options.

---

## PDFSharp

You could try [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)
it has an [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
which means according to what it says here you should be able to use in a commercial product.

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>   in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
>   to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
>   copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
>   furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

---

## FreeSpire.Doc

There's also [FreeSpire.Doc](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-word-for-net-free.html) ([on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/)), which is limited to 3 pages and 500 paragraphs. It can convert Word documents to PDFs.

Answer (score 4):

The AGPL basically states that you can use iTextSharp if any user of your application can have access to the source code of both iTextSharp (along with the possible modifications you did on it) AND your application under the AGPL terms.
If you want to be released from these requirements, you have to pruchase a license from iText.

You'll find more information [here](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php).

If any doubt, don't hesitate to contact the sales department of iText.

So, in short Version 2 you can use without payment (standard library open source license). For version 5 you need to pay iText.